# Mocking a private member variable in gtest

Tags: c++, mocking, private, googletest

My intention is to test a function which calls two different functions based on the value of a boolean. The original class defined has the boolean declared as private. And the function is of the form:

```
funcA()
{
  if(B) funcB;
  else funcC;
}
```

Here B is the private member boolean variable whose value is changed in some other function and is by default defined as false.
I want to write a google test case for this class where I want to use `EXPECT_CALL(*classInstance, funcB).Times(1)` if B is true and `EXPECT_CALL(*classInstance, funcC).Times(1)` otherwise. Can someone please tell me how we can change the value of the boolean B within the test case?

Comment: In the unit testing sessions I attended, if you need to write unit tests against the privates, that's a good sign that the class is probably violating *single responsibility principle*, and those privates really ought to be refactored into a separate class.  Then that newly refactored out separate class can be unit tested.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell me how we can change the value of the boolean B within the test case?

You cannot*, that's the whole point of `private` members. The good news - you shouldn't.
Test observable behaviour of your class, not its details (like a private boolean variable).

I see two test cases here:

- `funcC` is called when `funcA` is called rigth after unit under test is created, and
- `funcB` is called if `someOtherFuncThatChangesB` is called before `funcA`.

---

*[There are ways](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#testing-private-code) to access private members, but they are generally not recommended. `private` parts should be possible to be freely changed without a change in tests (as long as logic stays the same).